# regex extract number before and after hyphen

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract a math formula from a string; the pattern is almost the same.

GA 28-32 wks: **10 to 12 mm/kk/day**, Q6-8h;

I want to extract the Bold text from the string.
Another type from the string.
**10-15 g/kg/week**, Q6h

```
\b\d+-\d+\b|\/[a-zA-Z]|
```

But I can't get the result I want.
Thank you.

Comment: You title and your question are not asking the same thing.  In the first example, the numbers before and after the hyphen are `28, 32, 6, and 8`.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expanding out your original pattern some to match the slash parts, adding "dash or 'to'", and accounting for the spaces in the string, would be something like this:

```
\b\d+\s*(to|-)\s*\d+\b\s*[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-z]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/KSqtcX/1/

Comment: Thank you, there is something I do not mention in the question,  what if I have one number like 40 rr/dd/day.

Comment: i think you can make the whole first part optional:  `(?:\b\d+\s*(to|-)\s*)?\d+\b\s*[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[A-Za-z]+`